# How to compare two timestamps in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, datetime

I am new to Python and I need to know how to compare timestamps.

**I have the following example:**

```
timestamp1: Feb 12 08:02:32 2015
timestamp2: Jan 27 11:52:02 2014
```

How can I calculate how many days or hours are from `timestamp1` to `timestamp2`?

How can I know which timestamp is the latest one?

Comment: Search *datetime*. And see how to use it.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use [`datetime.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to convert those strings into [`datetime` objects](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects), then get a [`timedelta` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) by simply subtracting them or find the largest using [`max`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max):

```
from datetime import datetime

timestamp1 = "Feb 12 08:02:32 2015"
timestamp2 = "Jan 27 11:52:02 2014"

t1 = datetime.strptime(timestamp1, "%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
t2 = datetime.strptime(timestamp2, "%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")

difference = t1 - t2

print(difference.days) # 380, in this case

latest = max((t1, t2)) # t1, in this case
```

You can get information on `datetime.strptime` formats [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Comment: if they are already in Timestamp('2020-01-01 20:00:00") can I just do <, <= or >, >= to compare it with another Timestamp value? when I try it it works but want to make sure if python is really comparing dates

Comment: @Ambleu well what is `Timestamp`? It will depend on the comparison methods implemented by that class, but that's not in the standard library.

Comment: @jonrsharpe `TimeStamp` is a `pandas` class: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html

Answer (score 6):

First you need to convert those *strings* into an object on which Python can do calculations.  This is done using the `strptime` method of the `datetime` module.

```
import datetime

s1 = 'Feb 12 08:02:32 2015'
s2 = 'Jan 27 11:52:02 2014'

d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(s1, '%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(s2, '%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')

print(d1-d2)
```

This will print `380 days, 20:10:30`