# How to compare 2 timestamps (date + time + timezone)

Tags: python

I got 2 dates from my database and I need to compare if one date is greater than another one.
I got the date in this format:

```
2018-11-07 18:00:40.679087+00:00
2018-11-14 00:00:17.908676+00:00
```

I tried a lot of solutions, but I didn't figured it out how it works fine.

ps.: I got a lot of questions that looks like this one, but in my case I have the timezone to consider that's the difference.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378977/compare-two-timestamps-in-python).

Comment: I tried this one, but in my case the format of date contains timezone

Comment: Read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)! `%z`UTC offset in the form ±HHMM[SS[.ffffff]]. later on: *Changed in version 3.7:* UTC offsets can have a colon as a separator between hours, minutes and seconds

Comment: That's the point @ChristianKönig. Tku so much.

Comment: @Networker in my case I have the timezone to consider, that's the difference. I tried a lot of things that I found here, but none of them works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
from dateutil import parser
date1='2018-11-07 18:00:40.679087+00:00'
date2='2018-11-14 00:00:17.908676+00:00'
print parser.parse(date2) - parser.parse(date1)

Result:6 days, 5:59:37.229589
```

Comment: That's an elegant way to solve it. Tku

Comment: Glad to hear this helps u ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one (using built-in Python module):

```
from datetime import datetime

d1 = "2018-11-07 18:00:40.679087+00:00"
d2 = "2018-11-14 00:00:17.908676+00:00"

d1 = d1[:d1.rfind(":")] + d1[d1.rfind(":")+1:]
d2 = d2[:d2.rfind(":")] + d2[d2.rfind(":")+1:]

t1 = datetime.strptime(d1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z")
t2 = datetime.strptime(d2, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z")

diff = t2 - t1
print(diff)
```

Output:

```
6 days, 5:59:37.229589
```

Comment: no need to insert/remove the `:` for Python 3.7

Comment: I am running Python 3.6 and I am getting `ValueError` if I don't remove it.

Answer (score 0):

The `:` is bugging you, you can parse it like:

```
d = '2018-11-07 18:00:40.679087+00:00'
d = d[:-3]+d[-2:]
datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')

datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 7, 18, 0, 40, 679087, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Comment: no need to insert/remove the `:` for Python 3.7