# Using Python for .csv import into postgreSQL : Eliminate Duplicates

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, duplicates

A project I am working on has a .csv file that is updated every 10 minutes. I want to read that data into SQL the moment it is updated. I already have a powershell script monitoring the ftp folder that the .csv is imported into. The watchdog powershell activates a batch file to rename the .csv into a fixed name, import it into sql, and then delete it. The code below does successfully import the values from the .csv into the SQL table. The only thing I have left is to parse through duplicates while the batch file is running to avoid adding them to the table.

***Python Code***

```
import csv
import pyodbc

#connect to database
#DB connection string
print("Establishing Database connection...")
con = pyodbc.connect('DSN=testdatabase')
cursor = con.cursor()
print("...Connected to database.")


#read file and copy data into analysis server table
print("Reading file contents and copying into database...")
with open('C:\\Users\\CurrentUser\\Desktop\\test1.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    next(readCSV) #skips the header row
    for row in readCSV: 
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO testtable (id, year, month, day) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",
            row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3])
        con.commit()
print("...Completed reading file contents and copying into database.")
```

The SQL table will continually take on data without truncating, so doing something with MERGE WITH may work well at first, but will quickly be bogged down after a few days as the code will have to compare the .csv against more and more data. I was thinking to save the last row from the initial .csv into a separate file to call upon later. During the next 10 min import iteration, recall that information and compare it to the new .csv starting from the bottom. The first cell is a timestamp of sorts so to compare, I'm thinking to incorporate this from another stack overflow question,
[How to compare two timestamps in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378977/how-to-compare-two-timestamps-in-python)

```
from datetime import datetime

timestamp1 = "Feb 12 08:02:32 2015"
timestamp2 = "Jan 27 11:52:02 2014"

t1 = datetime.strptime(timestamp1, "%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
t2 = datetime.strptime(timestamp2, "%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")

difference = t1 - t2
```

The format of my timestamp is as such,

```
%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f
```

I will mention that the powershell script didnt work well with multiple files arriving into the ftp folder at once, so I have a lot of data coming into one .csv. What I mean by that is about 160+ columns. That's a lot for the INSERT INTO format to take though I'm perfectly willing to add all the column headers and values if there isn't a better method.

So to summarize,is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do? Has anyone else done something similar where I'm not reinventing the wheel? and If there isn't a better way to do what I'm trying to do, does my method sound plausible? Much appreciated.

Comment: You want automate import csv  to postgresql also make no duplicated? you can make some unique constraints to make sure no duplicates. there is some scripts there to automate, this part I am nor sure.

Comment: The general procedure for this is to: 1) Use [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) to import the `CSV` into a staging table 2) Determine what constitutes a duplicate 3) Then use `INSERT INTO final_table ... WHERE ...` . The `WHERE` being the portion that determines the non-duplicate values in the staging table that can be inserted into the final table. 4) `TRUNCATE` the staging table and repeat with next batch.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
import pyodbc
import time
from datetime import datetime

#connect to database
#DB connection string
print("Establishing Database connection...")
con = pyodbc.connect('DSN=SQLdatabase')
cursor = con.cursor()
print("...Connected to database.")

#recall last timestamp entry in db table

t1 = datetime.strptime(cursor.execute("SELECT MAX(id) FROM test;").fetchval(), "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f")


#read file and copy data into table
print("Reading file contents and copying into table...")
with open('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\test2.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    columns = next(readCSV) #skips the header row
    t2 = datetime.strptime(next(readCSV)[0], "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
    while t2 < t1:
        t2 = datetime.strptime(next(readCSV)[0], "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
    query = 'insert into test({0}) values ({1})'
    query = query.format(','.join(columns), ','.join('?' * len(columns)))
    for data in readCSV:
        cursor.execute(query, data)
    con.commit()
print("Data posted to table")
```

This is where I ended up. Works well and eliminates the need to put headers into the "insert into" expression. Skipped the staging table and just kept the .csv contents in an array until the remaining code determined what needed to be added.